# Insert text into a variable within a switch statement

Tags: powershell

I'm currently making a slot machine for fun. I have this switch:

```
switch ($gevinst) {
    '!!!' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 50 dollarz'
        $vundet += 50
    }                        
    '+++' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 80 dollarz'
        $vundet += 80
    }
    '%%%' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 150 dollarz'
        $vundet += 150
    }
    '???' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 200 dollarz'
        $vundet += 200
    }
    '===' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 700 dollarz'
        $vundet += 700
    }
    '&&&' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 1500 dollars'
        $vundet += 1500
    }
    '£££' {
        'Tillykke du har vundet 5000 dollarz'
        $vundet += 5000
    }
    Default {
        if (($1 + $2 -eq '!!') -or ($2 + $3 -eq '!!')) {
            'Tillykke du har vundet 30 dollarz'
            $vundet += 30
        }
        else {
            'Desværre du tabte'
        }
    }
}
```

and whenever I roll `!!!` it will add 50 bucks to my "account".
However, I'm expanding my game by making a "History" menu button where you can see your wins and looses.

My question is, what do I do if I want a specific text to be added to a variable `$History`?

Example: everytime I roll `!!!` I get 50 dollars to my `$vundet` and then `You have won` to my `$History`

ps. If anyone need the whole code for an answer, then I will gladly E-mail it to you.

Answer (score 3):

Just define the `$History` *above* your switch:
`$History = @()`

Then you can *add* the value within your switch:

```
'!!!' {
    'Tillykke du har vundet 50 dollarz'
    $vundet+= 50
    $history += 'Tillykke du har vundet 50 dollarz'
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Well i is posible to add `n for new line, so everytime i win the 50 bucks it makes a new line to the $history?

Comment: `$history` is an array, so depending how you wan't to present the messages you should already see a new line for each entry.